# Did microsoft drop "Dynamic" & "Static" wording from Arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dynamic-arrays, ilist

After so many years, today I decided to look back into some complicated syntax related to arrays and didn't take much time until I realized Microsoft doesn't mention to **Dynamic** side of [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) anymore and all the examples are **Static**. I literally needed to do a quick search to find out that they moved the concept under a new wording as [ArrayList Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or the more generic lists as [List Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

I just want to clarify this change and the fact that if I need to use the new naming to communicate with our new programmers since they might not being taught the old naming conventions in the university or online courses.

**MSDN Reference**

> ArrayList Class (.NET Framework 4.5)
>
> Implements the `IList` interface using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.

```
  // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList.
  ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
```

and `List<T>` as

```
  // Create a list of parts.
  List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
```

**Please read this before you go ahead**. What I am asking is: If Microsoft dropped the **WORDING** from it's glossaries of **WORDS** relating to Arrays or any Objects of strongly typed lists as called "**Dynamic Arrays**".

Comment: **Never** use ArrayList, thats why we have List<T> now. Note the remarks in the MSDN page you linked: "For a strongly-typed alternative to ArrayList, consider using List<T>."

Comment: Are you sure that arrays in C# having a fixed length is a change? Sounds like something that has always been that way (and rather impossible to change).

Comment: @Thilo, I am not talking the basics but the wording. I mean when I was in the uni, dinosaur years ago, the first word used to follow the `Array` was that they can be two types, Static and Dynamic. And now looking at Arrays reference for C# in MSDN if you're a newbie you won't ever know from that page that there is such concept exists as an dynamic `Array` and you come across this concept when you're studying `Lists`. :)

Comment: Thats because there are no "dynamic arrays" anymore its just a list. In my studies ( a few years back ) we were taught to always use Lists for dynamic amounts of data, I imagine most people are the same.

Comment: _Arrays aren't dynamic_ and never have been. When they appear dynamic, it is an abstraction over the top of an array that creates an even bigger array and copies the old one into the new one. Memory cannot just be expanded randomly.. think of how much memory fragmentation you would have on your machine if that were possible / allowed.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Do you know what I mean when I use the word "**Dynamic Array**"? if yes and even if you used this forbidden word in the past by mistake, you might need to consider an 18 year old who is extremely good in C# and started from .Net 3.0 might not. You know how I know it? cuz I didn't before you write the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and `ArrayList` is effectively "dropped" as well (even though it still exists). The page you linked about `ArrayList` states:

> For a strongly-typed alternative to ArrayList, consider using `List<T>`.

And that's exactly what you should do. [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) (introduced in .NET 2.0) were intended to fix the problems with having a bunch of weakly-typed ArrayLists everywhere. Use `List<T>` (or another generic collection) when you need a dynamically sized collection of items.

Answer (score 2):

While *dynamic* is indeed the opposite of *static* in english, it's true that in C# and other similar languages (like Java) the common use for these terms is changed. What you call an immutable length array is often referred as **fixed** while an expandable collection like an `ArrayList` (or better `List<T>`, as others pointed) is just referred as dynamically sizable. *Static* is now more often used to express the concept of *class* members while *dynamic* is often used to express the general concept the of runtime binding, as opposed to compile time, "static" binding. Binding could be, for example, method resolution or variable expansion.